# Flask: No module named Routes

Tags: python, flask, importerror

Im trying a small tutorial of flask when I encountered an error in my file structures.

```
\flaskapp
   \app
       - runserver.py
       - __init__.py
        \intro_to_flask
           - __init__.py
           -forms.py
           -routes.py
           -statics
           -templates
```

Now my init file has:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'development key'

app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'contact@example.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'your-password'

from routes import mail //IMPORTERROR: No modules named routes 
mail.init_app(app)

import intro_to_flask.routes
```

my routes.py has the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask_mail import Message, Mail

mail = Mail()

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')
//and more...
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField,   validators, ValidationError

class ContactForm(Form):
name = TextField("Name",  [validators.Required("Please enter your name.")])
email = TextField("Email",  [validators.Required("Please enter your email address."), validators.Email("Please enter your email address.")])
subject = TextField("Subject",  [validators.Required("Please enter a subject.")])
message = TextAreaField("Message",  [validators.Required("Please enter a message.")])
submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

I was working on this as a small module until the tutorial suggested to changed it to a package structure. I created a new directory with the same files just in case but no luck :(

Comment: try from `intro_to_flask.routes import mail`

Comment: add  empy `__init__.py` under `intro_to_flask` folder

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I edited to import intro_to_flask.routes, it didnt work. Im assuming by empty init.py you mean either in the app file or erase the content of my current init.py file under flaskapp/app/intro_to_flask. Both dont work :(

Comment: replacing `from routes import mail` to `from .routes import mail` fixing your problem?

Comment: also try to add `__init__.py` on app level.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko replacing "from routes" to "from .routes" pops up another ImportError:"No module named 'forms'". Seems like this is going somewhere.

Comment: you have syntax error in routes, remove obscure indentation before `def home`

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko oops sorry that was me when I was submiting the code to stack overflow. The actual file has no indentation on def home()

Comment: ensure you have empty  `__init__.py` in each working directory and use simple import as in initial question

Comment: Should I also empty the main init.py file? The one one intro_to_flask?